# Duda al llamar a la función

Tags: c, funciones

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void mostrarmenu ()
{
    printf ("                                  BIENVENIDOS A MI PRIMER PROGRAMA :V");
    printf ("\n 1. Numero de hola's'");
    printf ("\n 0. Salir");
    printf ("\n Digite opcion ");

}

main()
{
    int opcion = 0, c=1, n;
    {
        mostrarmenu();
        opcion = getchar();
        switch (opcion)
        {
        case '1' : printf ("Digite el numero de Holas que desee: ");
            scanf ("%d" , &n);
            printf ("El numero de holas son; %d" ,  mensaje(n,c));
        }
    }
    while (opcion != '0');
}




void mensaje(int n, int c)

{

    if(c<=n)
    {
        printf ("\n Hola");
        mensaje (n, c+1);
    }

}
```

El problema es que me sale lanza el siguiente error:

> 'MENSAJE' WAS NOT DECLARED IN THIS SCOPE.

Comment: Eso se debe a que la función `main`,  utiliza una función aún sin declararse, recuerda que debes declarar una función antes de usarla, la solución más simple, es mover el contenido de `mensaje` antes de `main` (como hiciste con `mostrarmenu`) o bien agrega el prototipado de la función, la línea `void mensaje(int, int);` antes de `main`solucionaría tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que tienes es porque estas declarando tu funcion abajo del main si antes haber declarado su correspondiente prototipo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//se declara el prototipo de la funcion mensaje;
void mensaje(int n, int c);
```

Ahora si reconoceria la funcion mensaje dentro del main, pero tienes ahora otra inconveniente que la funcion mensaje no retorna nada por lo tanto te dara un error que dice **"invalid use of void expression"** en ese caso tienes dos opciones o retornas un valor cuando llamas a la funcion mensaje o usas la funcion mensaje afuera de la funcion printf

Ejemplo

```
scanf ("%d" , &n);
printf ("El numero de holas son ");
mensaje(n,c);
```

Comment: Para el prototipado se suele omitir los nombres de las variables, y listar simplemente el tipo. A no ser claro que el prototipo esté en un `.h` y actúe como interfaz pública, en cuyo caso se suele explicitar el nombre por motivos de documentación propia.